# Laravel Query Builder fetch multiple table

Tags: laravel

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE name = ?");
$statement->execute(array($name));
$author_id = $statement->fetch()["id"];

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE author_id = ?");
$statement->execute(array($author_id));
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {
$quote =  $row['quote'];
    }
```

How can i do same operation in laravel query builder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$where[] = ['authors.name ', $name];
$data = \DB::table('authors')
    ->join('quotes', 'quotes.author_id', '=', 'authors.id')
    ->where($where)
    ->get();
```